# Qual seria o equivalente a delegar no JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando um elemento é criado dinamicamente pelo JS e esse elemento precisa executar uma função eu faço assim no jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button#doLogin', function(){

});
```

Como é isso no JS puro ? 
**Vanilla.js**

Comment: *Não seria isso que procuras?* document.addEventListener

Comment: Duplicata de qual pergunta?